# make IntPtr in C#.NET point to string value

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, interop

I am using a class which has `StringHandle` field which is an `IntPtr` value that represents a
`LPCWSTR` in C++.

```
internal IntPtr StringHandle; // LPCWSTR
```

say now that I have a String: `string x = "abcdefg"`

How can I use the String handle to point to the beginning of the String so that it is like C++ LPCWSTR ?

Comment: I am working with interface that only exists in native code (C++) so I am using Interops from .NET. however, the class that has StringHandle is not mine and I don't want to change.

Comment: Because that's what the library he's working with expects. Not everything has a .NET wrapper built for it, and even within the Framework the Marshal class can get some good use when you're dealing with things like low-level Windows messages.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to copy the string to the unmanaged memory first and then get the `IntPtr` from that location. You can do so like:

```
IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(x);
```

also, you need to make sure to free the unmanaged memory:

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strPtr);
```

it's best to do all this in a try/finally.

Comment: I actually needed this one Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni  since I am using COM but thank you

Answer (score 7):

Managed strings *move* in memory when the garbage collector compacts the heap.  So they don't have a stable address and can't directly be cast to a LPCWSTR.  You'll need to either pin the string with GCHandle.Alloc() to use GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject or copy it into unmanaged memory with Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni().

Strongly prefer copying if the address needs to be stable for a while.

Comment: Does `AddrOfPinnedObject` on a `string` give you a pointer to the character data (`LPCWSTR` as mentioned in the question)?  (According to http://www.drdobbs.com/pinning-in-managed-c/184403869: Yes)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use one of the StringTo* methods on the [`Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) class