# Why can't we take a pointer to a string?

Tags: c#, pointers, intptr

With the following codes:

```
static unsafe void Main( string[] args )
{
  int a = 5;
  IntPtr pa = new IntPtr( &a );  // no error
  var xa =  pa.ToPointer();

  string b = "test";
  IntPtr pb = new IntPtr( &b );   // compile error
  var xb = pb.ToPointer();
}
```

It generate compile error:

*Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('type')*

What's wrong with having a pointer to a managed type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299153/cannot-take-the-address-of-get-the-size-of-or-declare-a-pointer-to-a-managed-t)

Comment: possible duplicate of [make IntPtr in C#.NET point to string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090427/make-intptr-in-c-net-point-to-string-value)

Comment: The compiler is 100% convinced that you can't dereference that IntPtr correctly.  It is right, the string can be destroyed at any moment, nanoseconds after you initialized the IntPtr.  The .NET garbage collector is *not* a conservative collector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that managed objects can be moved around in memory as a side-effect of garbage collection of other objects, thus invalidating any pointers to them.

The `int` you are taking the address of is on the stack, and will not be moved around in memory - thus it is safe to access a pointer to it. (Well, as safe as using pointers can be...)